# Global variable not being updated by override function

Tags: java

Im having an issue getting my override function of doGet to update my global arrayList variable "list" so that I can then iterate over it inside of the doPost function. Im somewhat rusty with java as I havent used it in some time, so I cant seem to find the issue other than suspecting it has something to do with the fact that Im using override function(s). Any help appreciated, code is below.

```java
public class MembershipControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public static ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String action=request.getParameter("action");
        String url="/index.html";

        if (action == null) {
            action="";
        }
        else if (action.equals("signup")) {
            url="/signup.jsp";
        }
        else{
            String m = "";
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            String user = request.getParameter("userName");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            String address = request.getParameter("address");
            String countries[] = request.getParameterValues("countries");
            String zip = request.getParameter("zip");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            String male = request.getParameter("male");
            String female = request.getParameter("female");
            String langs[] = request.getParameterValues("lang");


         if (name.isEmpty() || user.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || address.isEmpty() || countries.length ==0 || zip.isEmpty() ||
                 email.isEmpty() || male == null || female == null || langs.length ==0) 
         {
            m = "Please enter all data";  
            list.add(m);
         }
         else
         {
           m = "name: " + name;
           list.add(m);
         }
        }


         processRequest(request, response);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response); 
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

     try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
         /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */

         String newmsg= "";
         for (Object li : list) {
             newmsg += li;
         }
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet MembershipControllerServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>" + newmsg + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
```

and the xml file:

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MembershipControllerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>edu.uncc.nbad.MembershipControllerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>


     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MembershipControllerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/membership</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>signup.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

finally signup.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Registration Form</h1>

        <form method = "post" action = "/Lab3-Hitz-Herron/membership?action=signup">
            <label>Name</label><input class = 'box' type = 'text' name = "name"><br />
            <label>UserName:</label><input class = 'box' type = 'text' name =
            "userName"><br />
            <label>Password: </label><input class = 'box' type = 'text' name =
            "password"><br />
            <label>Address:</label><input class = 'box' type = 'text' name =
            "address"><br />
            <label>Country:</label>
            <select class= "box" name = 'countries'>
                <option value="USA">USA</option>
                <option value="OTHER">Other</option> </select
            ><br />
            <label>Zip Code:</label> <input class="box" type="text" name ="zip" /><br />
            <label>Email: </label> <input class="box" type="email" email namd ="email" /><br />
            <label>Sex: </label> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" name ="male" />Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" name = "female"/>Female<br />
            <label>Language:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="English" name ="lang" />English
            <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="French" name ="lang"/>French
            <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="German" name ="lang" />German <br />
            About:
            <textarea name = "about"></textarea><br />
                        <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you use your code? What are your parameters?

Comment: And just for the record: making that list `static` is most likely wrong. Or do you really want that **all** instances of that service use the same list? Beyond that: when you are rusty with Java, you should probably start with less challenging projects than servlet programming.

Comment: remove list. add method from if block 

         if (name.isEmpty() || user.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || address.isEmpty() || countries.length ==0 || zip.isEmpty() ||
                 email.isEmpty() || male == null || female == null || langs.length ==0) 
         {
            m = "Please enter all data";  
            list.add(m);
         }

Also how are you calling or mapping your controller.

Comment: as per my understanding, your list related code is fine. you just need to remove list.add() from if block. List will have data. empty list should be problem of your request mapping. are you using prototype scope for bean or application context

Comment: @SSP Thanks for that insight, I considered if it being in the if block would affect it. Also, I'm not sure what you mean about prototype or application context? I'm a student and in a class where this was the first assignment so I'm lacking much knowledge on this topic. We were given a vague instruction document and told to follow the steps with hardly any explanation of what we were actually doing.

Comment: how are you calling doget and dopost method

Comment: also what are the technology and framework are you using?

Comment: Diamond Reference your ArrayList declaration: `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` (add the **<>**). If your ArrayList **list** object is of **String** type why are you iterating through it as **Object** within the doPost() method? Try: `StringBuilder newmsg = new StringBuilder(); for (String li : list) { newmsg.append(li); }`. And where you use **newmsg**: `out.println("<h1>" + newmsg.toString() + "</h1>");`

Comment: @SSP Im calling the methods in the jsp file using the "method =" from my understanding. Im also mapping the servlet using the xml file. Ill add the code for both the jsp and the xml file to the original post above so you can take a look at it. Sorry for the lack of understanding, the professor has done a teribble job at explaining what exactly we are doing and instead intends for us to blindly follow "how-to" documents leaving myself and numerous classmates beyond confused about what each thing even does.

Comment: Something not related to the question, but you are mixing GET and POST in what they are supposed to be used for. POST is (mostly) to create data and GET to retrieve data. The code you shared has it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Never do this!

You have a concurrency issue with this implementation known as a race condition because list will be shared between threads.